# Finding the period of complex exponential function

Tags: signal-processing, periodic-functions

I am having some trouble finding the period of the following discrete signal:

$x[n]=e^{jn2\pi/3}+e^{jn3\pi/4}$

Comment: You probably mean [primitive period](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_function#Definition).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a composition of two complex exponentials each with it's own fundamental frequency. $$e^{j2\pi f_0n}$$ This way the exponentials would have frequencies $$f_1 = \frac{1}{3}$$ $$f_2 = \frac{3}{8}$$ And because neither of both frequencies can be simplified anymore then the fundamental period is defined to be the denominator of the expressions above so $$ T_1 = 3 $$ $$ T_2 = 8 $$

[image: Graph!]

Comment: When we sum these two signals, how can we calculate the period of the result?

Comment: As far as I know there is not such one period, because there is going to be one signal that repeats after very long time.  So I think it depends of what is your signal of interest. I edited the post to show the graph.

Comment: Also I have to warning you that the plot I'm showing is a continuos graph and it did interpolating data, but your complex exponentials are in the discrete domain, so don't make the assumption that the period is 24 as could be deduced from the graph. I'm in my iPad now so i'm not able to plot discrete data, but you can try using Matlab and the "stem" command.

Answer (score 2):

To sum up, our singal is periodic (because it is a superposition of two periodic signals) and **it's primitive period is equal to the Least Common Multiple of the periods of the two composing signals**. In this case LCM{3,8} = 24.

So the (primitive) period of the above-mentioned signal is T = 24.